# Where can I get Android 2.2 for HTC Desire

Tags: htc-desire

How can I get the 2.2 version of Android on my HTC Desire and when?

Answer (score 10):

I just got the update notification (unbranded Desire, Germany).

So the answer to "when" is: Now.

Comment: @balpha, thanks! How did you received the notification? Is that an url that you got?  Can you download it over wifi? - sorry about the questions. I just got really excited

Comment: @gyurisc just a popup saying that it's there and asks if you want to download over any connection or only when connected to wifi (it's some 90mb). Rest happens automatically, except for a "ready when you are" dialog to confirm the install.

Comment: did you keep all your settings?

Comment: Hi! I managed to force it by going to the Settings then About phone and then System Software updates. There I did a Check now and downloaded the update over WiFi. I had to try this several times as it said that the download is corrupted. I got lucky at the end and the update is installed.

Comment: @Moak It kept all my settings. I could not notice any changes in my setup, so it is fine.

Answer (score 7):

The official Froyo release for the HTC Desire seems to [be imminent](http://phandroid.com/2010/06/22/htc-delivering-froyo-to-the-htc-desire-and-legend-within-the-next-two-weeks/). Though since it's already been over *three* weeks since they said it would come within the next *two*, you might have better luck with an [unofficial ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=690477).

Comment: The article linked to (and many others elsewhere reporting the same story) turned out to be incorrect. The information appears to have come from someone quite low down within HTC and was inaccurate. The official statement has now been released as per my other answer.

Answer (score 5):

The initial leaked information was "late June", but this turned out to be incorrect. HTC have released a full statement now stating that the upgrade will be during Q3 (so anytime between now and the end of September). See this [TechRadar article](http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/htc-desire-android-2-2-update-coming-in-q3-699715) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article about putting a custom [2.2 on your HTC Desire](http://blog.icanhaspi.com/archives/732), I've heard first hand reports that it worked.